# Finding features for classifying document into printable or non-printable

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nltk, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I would like to perform a binary classification of documents (.txt, .pdf, .jpeg, .img, etc.) into two categories: printable and non-printable.  Essentially our school runs a free printing service for clubs, but the reality is that many clubs abuse the free printing and end up printing their homework, papers, etc., which amounts to thousands of dollars in ink and paper.  Thus we would like to take some unsupervised methods to help limit this by determining whether a document is with high probability not club related (e.g. Biophysics paper, there is no biophysics club!).

So this is a very simple binary classification problem.  I am not looking for low-level implementation details or which ML algorithms I should use, but rather how I should discover the relevant features that will then be fed to the training, etc.

My first idea was to gather all the documents that students print in the library.  The idea is that if you have actual club printing, you'll do it for free at the club printing center rather than pay for it at the library.  That would be a massive dataset, assuming every document printed at the library is assigned the non-printable/club material category.  Unfortunately, the school is very liberal and opposed to allowing this due to privacy concerns, so it is not really an option without legal risks.

A similar-minded option would be to collect documents that are tied to courses / school work, e.g. course syllabi, available course documents online (homeworks, papers, etc.) and do feature extraction / selection on these.  The assumption is that students would be abusing the printing to generally print material relevant to their studies.

While for .pdf and .txt based document this approach should have reasonable performance, I am at a loss at how to classify image based documents, besides perhaps using the title of the document and other meta data.  A clever violator could simply convert all their text documents to image format to circumvent this system.  However that is outside the scope of this question and should be saved for a future question / research.  For now the scope is just text based documents.

Note that there are previous questions on topics similar to this, but mine is very specific and I believe it may pose challenges that something like movie review classification might not have to face.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to leave a comment but it ended way longer than what I imagined.

While this is an interesting problem I'm not sure ML will get you what you need easily.

Firstly your classification problem is of the type `A vs the World` and `A` isn't strictly defined. Unless you know exactly what kind of stuff the clubs print you can't really say that new material belong or no to that class.

This will prove particularly difficult when you will need to assemble a large enough training set to be able to cover whatever can or cannot be printed. Such task will be extremely tedious, and as you said you won't have access to what the clubs usually print out so at best you will have a large class imbalance in your training set.

As the goal is to make the system automated (I mean if there is human interaction anyway, it's faster to check what will be printed than to make a ML algorithm that will provide a score that a human will have to investigate anyway) the number of false positives and false negatives will also be problematic. There will be cases where the clubs won't be able to print things they have the right to.

As you said you could simplify greatly the problem by classifying `Course Material` and `Not Course Material`. For that I will look towards BoW because some words are more present than others in papers or course material (everything remotely technical). The number of words as well as the overall size of the file seem like sensible things to extract. The structure is often also particular : it might be a good idea to extract such things : "number of lines with less than x words", "number of lines per page", "number of pictures" (if that's something you can extract from the file), ...

For pictures the major thing to check would be if this a scan of something (often they will scan and print course related things I guess), for that the format of the image is already a good indication but I don't see other things that would be particularly "course related".

So for me, if you can't really define precisely one of your two classes don't go with classification or reduce the problem to something you can really define (course related things).

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to compile a "black list" of documents students are not allowed to print, you can then implement a several layers rejection mechanism.

I would suggest these 3 levels:

1. compare the md5 of the file they want to print with a database of all the md5 of the black-listed documents.
2. if the 1) is passed, compare repeat 1) but at a page level, rather than at document level (perhaps they want to print just few pages rather than the entire document).
3. if 2) is passed you can compare the page they want to print with the pages of the black-listed documents document using an image similarity method, like [SSIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity). if you get a high score between the page they want print and one of the black-listed items do not print, and update your md5 database accordingly.
4. if 3) is passed: print!

A few words about SSIM: this method is quite robust to noise, so even a smart student who added some sort of niose to the image will be caught
However:

- you have to find a proper way to extract a region of interest (ROI) from the page and the db of documents (if the two ROIs are in two different area of the page, SSIM will be negative)
- SSIM might be slow! definitely a C implementation is needed here.
- I think SSIM is not rotational invariant, hence the check will fail if they print the page upside down (unless you have a smart way to rotate the page).